# Java JButton text and focus displaying incorrectly, overlapping

Tags: java, swing, text, duplicates, jbutton

I've created a simple swing GUI with JButtons. When I start the GUI, [this is what it looks like](http://prntscr.com/8y2q1j).

[image]

If I click on each button once, [it looks like this.](http://prntscr.com/8y2qda)

[image]

How do I remove the phantom text that on each button, and how do I remove the dark gray focus on buttons that have been clicked?
Below is my button class

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MenuButton extends JButton{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     public MenuButton(String text, JPanel container){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(container.getSize().width),50));
        setBackground(new Color(168, 228, 247, 0));
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setText(text);
        setOpaque(false);
        setFocusPainted(false);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setRolloverEnabled(false);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    public void addTo(JPanel container){
        container.add(this);
    }
}
```

I created a new instance of the "MenuButton" in main and added it to my Jpanel called JMenu, but have done nothing further. So all it should do at the moment is display a JButton with the appropriate text, and without all of the hover/click/mouseover highlighting effects.

Comment: We're probably going to need the parent `JPanel`, though I'm not sure why you're setting opaque to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setBackground(new Color(168, 228, 247, 0));
setOpaque(false);
```

You have conflicting parameters. You are saying the button is transparent (so you don't want the background painted) but you try to give it a background color with an alpha value.

Use one or the other, but not both.

If you do decide that you want a background with an alpha value then you will have painting problems. Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation of the problem and a couple of solutions.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the overlapping text issue. Do you happen to know why the first Jbutton is highlighted on launch, and the other after being pressed?

Comment: using 'setFocusable(false);' removed the highlight from the first JButton, but they all are still permanently highlighted when clicked...